# having problems with index out of range errors

Tags: python

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit =  suit
        self.rank = rank
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.rank['rank']} of {self.suit}"    

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        suits = ["spades", "clubs", "hearts", "diamonds",]
        ranks = [                                           
                {"rank": "A", "value": 11},
                {"rank": "2", "value": 2},
                {"rank": "3", "value": 3},
                {"rank": "4", "value": 4},
                {"rank": "5", "value": 5},
                {"rank": "6", "value": 6},
                {"rank": "7", "value": 7},
                {"rank": "8", "value": 8},
                {"rank": "9", "value": 9},
                {"rank": "10", "value": 10},
                {"rank": "J", "value": 10},
                {"rank": "Q", "value": 10},
                {"rank": "K", "value": 10},
            ]
                

        for suit  in suits:                  
            for rank in ranks:
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, rank))  

    def shuffle(self):   
        if len(self.cards) > 1:
            random.shuffle(self.cards)          
    def deal(self, number):
        cards_dealt = []
        for x in range(number):
            if len(self.cards) > 0:
                card = self.cards.pop()              
                cards_dealt.append(card)        
            return cards_dealt              


class Hand:
    def __init__(self, dealer = False):
        self.cards = []
        self.value = 0
        self.dealer = dealer
    
    def add_card(self, card_list):
        self.cards.extend(card_list)

deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()

hand = Hand()
hand.add_card(deck.deal(2))
print(hand.cards[1])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\learning python\BlackJack.py", line 66, in <module>
    print(hand.cards[1])
          ~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm trying to write a BlackJack game in Python and I'm trying to test the output of the cards, but when I try to output the two cards being picked its says that the list index is out of range. I don't really understand the problem I'm having.

I've looked through the code a bunch of times and I don't understand why there is a index out of range error.

IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: Have you tried, I don't know, printing the list?

Comment: If the list only has one card, and you try to output two cards, you'll get this error.

Comment: if list contains 7 items 0-6 is your list 7 is out of range

Comment: We can only make wild guesses unless you post a [mre].

Comment: Without showing us the actual code, and the full error traceback message, I don't know what kind of answer you expect us to give...

Comment: how do i show code this is my first time using this site

Comment: Edit the question and paste the code in there.  Make sure it is properly formatted -- select all the code and then click the `{}` code button.

Comment: Also post the full error trace message, so we know WHERE the error happened.

Answer (score 3):

```
def deal(self, number):
    cards_dealt = []
    for x in range(number):
        if len(self.cards) > 0:
            card = self.cards.pop()              
            cards_dealt.append(card)        
        return cards_dealt
```

In the `deal()` method, you have a `return` statement inside the `for x in range` loop.

`return` makes the function terminate immediately, so the loop will only run one time, even if you asked for more than one card.

Comment: thank you, I didn't even notice that indentation was off